# Can't pass realm data from tableViewController to viewController

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm having difficulty with passing a realm object's data from a tableViewController to a viewController. I want to choose one of the objects from the table and have that object's data be used in the following viewController. I've struggled to find resources here which deal with Realm objects instead of just passing strings and the likes. Any assistance would be great.

Here's my TableViewController with my attempt at creating a segue function to the second view :

```
class WorkoutController: UITableViewController {
    
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return DBHelper.shared.getWorkout().count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    if cell == nil {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }
    let muscle = DBHelper.shared.getWorkout()[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = muscle
    return cell
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let workoutDetailVC = segue.destination as! WorkoutDetail
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let name = DBHelper.shared.getWorkout()[indexPath.row]
        
        workoutDetailVC.receivedName = name
    }
}

}
```

Here's the WorkoutDetail class which is supposed to receive and show the data :

```
class WorkoutDetail: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var muscleLabel: UILabel!

var receivedName = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    muscleLabel.text = receivedName
}

}
```

Here is the getWorkout() function referenced above :

```
func getWorkout()-> [String] {
    var musclesName = [String]()
    let storedExercise = realm.objects(Workout1.self)
    for exercise in storedExercise {
        musclesName.append(exercise.exercise)
    }
    return musclesName
}
```

I'm having real difficulty with this and would very much appreciate some assistance, thanks.

Comment: You are not passing a realm object to your second view controller. You are passing a string, so it would be handled like passing any other string. Also, why do you have a tableview delegate function `didSelectRow:at` inside `prepare(forSegue`?

Answer (score 1):

Get `didSelectRowAt`  out of `prepare` then

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    if cell == nil {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }
    let muscle = DBHelper.shared.getWorkout()[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = muscle
    return cell
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let name = DBHelper.shared.getWorkout()[indexPath.row]
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier:"SegueName",sender:name)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let workoutDetailVC = segue.destination as! WorkoutDetail
    workoutDetailVC.receivedName = sender as! String
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have added this to my code and it builds and runs but when I attempt to perform the segue in the simulator I get the error "Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewCell' to 'NSString'".

Comment: It's `,sender:name)` not `,sender:self)`

Comment: In the 'self.performSegue()' snippet? As this is what I have in my project. The only change I had to make to your response was adding 'override' to the didSelectRow at function

Comment: Yes this is what I have but I am still getting the error, there is also a "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT" error when I attempt the segue